# parsing html using xpath hpple is always returning an empty string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xpath, html-parsing, hpple

I am doing the following:

```
NSData *htmlData = [[NSString stringWithString:sHTML] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
TFHpple * xpathParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:htmlData];
NSArray * elements  = [xpathParser searchWithXPathQuery:@"//div[@id='column2']"];
if ([elements count] > 0)
{
    TFHppleElement * element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString * sHTMLResult = [element content];
    ...
}
```

But, `sHTMLResult` (or, `[element content]`) is always empty.  I have tried `[element raw]` but that gives me a string with `<!CDATA` tags and carriage returns like `&13`.  In any case, the `CDATA` tags is what causes my html to be invalid when I use raw.

I have done a lot of google searches but they all seem to use `[element content]` so I am baffled as to what is wrong and why it does not work for me?

Comment: Can you also provide the sHTML variable's content?